# How to pass values from ASP.NET form to jQuery modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have an ASP.NET form that takes in several fields. When I click the submit button on the form, I'm trying to display a jQuery Modal that displays all of the fields that are filled out on the form (a verification window before submitting). Once I click "confirm" on the jQuery Modal, the ASP.NET form would submit the form to my server. I'm having issues passing the values from the ASP.NET form to the jQuery Modal.

ASP.NET FORM

```
<div class="row-fluid">
        <p class="row-fluid">
            <p class="span12 flush-left">
                <label for="txtECAccountNumber" class="span12">Account #</label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="span12" ID="txtECAccountNumber" MaxLength="50" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvECAccountNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Account # is required." Text="*Account # is required" ControlToValidate="txtECAccountNumber"
                    SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vgCreateCustomer" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revECAccountNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="A maximum of 50 characters is allowed for the account #." Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtECAccountNumber"
                    SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,50}$" ValidationGroup="vgCreateCustomer" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" />
            </p>
        </p>
        <p class="row-fluid">
            <p class="flush-left span12">
                <label for="txtECAccountName" class="span12">Account Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtECAccountName" CssClass="span12" MaxLength="100" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvECAccountName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Account name is required." Text="*Account name is required" ControlToValidate="txtECAccountName"
                    SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="vgCreateCustomer" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" EnableClientScript="true" />
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revECAccountName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="A maximum of 100 characters is allowed for the account name." Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtECAccountName"
                    SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,100}$" ValidationGroup="vgCreateCustomer" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="error" />
            </p>
        </p>
</div>
```

JQUERY FUNCTION

```
$("[id*=btnModalPopup]").live("click", function () {
    $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
        title: "Create Customer Verification",
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        modal: true,
        width: '800px'    
    });
    return false;
});
```

JQUERY MODAL DIALOG DISPLAY

```
<div id="modal_dialog" style="display: none;" >
    <p>Display ASP.NET form Values here</p>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet to get you started. Instead of having a `<div>` somewhere on the page with the modal content, the Modal can also create one from scratch.
Then you fill that Modal with the content generated in another function for example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id*=btnModalPopup]").live("click", function () {
        $('<div />').html(getModalContent()).dialog({
            title: "Create Customer Verification",
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            modal: true,
            width: '800px'
        });
        return false;
    });

    function getModalContent() {
        var content = " <p>Display ASP.NET form Values here</p>";
        content += "<br><br>";
        content += "<b>txtECAccountNumber:</b> " + document.getElementById("<%= txtECAccountNumber.ClientID %>").value + "<br>";
        content += "<b>txtECAccountName:</b> " + document.getElementById("<%= txtECAccountName.ClientID %>").value + "<br>";
        return content;
    }
</script>
```